# integrating android SQLite database with a web browser

Tags: sqlite

I need to create an android application which will insert some records in a database and the records of the database would be shown as output in a web browser. Is it possible to do this using android's SQLite database ? if yes then how ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: i am building an employee tracking system where the location of each employee will be stored in the database after a certain period of time  cycles. for example every 30 mins. the location is tracked using android's LocationManager. the admins will be able to see each employee's location by extracting the location information of that employee from the database. the result would be shown in webpage designed using html and jsp. what i wanted to know was that is it possible for an android application to access a database located in a web server ?